# Add button on block body using php

Tags: forms, blocks

How To Add PHP code to the body of a Drupal 7 Block

I just want to make a button on block body. Is that possible?

this link will explain what i want to do [add button]: http://drupal.org/node/1046700

> This article is for Drupal 7 developers who have tried to put PHP code
>   in the body of a Custom Block, but can't get it to run.

Comment: What do you want the button to do?

Comment: In that link there is a solution also.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you need this and you want a similar module of PHP filter which adds a new text format.

If you are familiar with [custom moduling](http://drupal.org/node/1074360) and [hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7), I would give you a straightforward solution.
You could implement this using [hook_block_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) by defining custom patterns (tokens).

```
<?php
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
    $patterns       = array('[add button]'); # more replacement patterns here
    $replacements   = array('<button type="button">Button</button>');
    if(isset($data['content'])){
        $content = $data['content'];
        if(is_string($content)) {
            $data['content'] = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);
        }
        elseif(is_array($content)) {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the result.

[image]
You may expand the code as you like such as defining more tokens, adding criteria for certain blocks, user roles, etc. You can even create an administration page at **admin/config** to define token replacements from UI.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `PHP filter` in the core modules